# Need a practical example for OOP Cobol?

Tags: oop, cobol

I'm a beginner, actually this semester I have to research about Cobol language. On the internet, there are few example, even no example about OOP cobol. There are only st like example for theory, they doesn't show me how to add st more ( like a main in Java ) to see the program work. 
I have some codes like this:

```
    class-id. A data is protected
               inherits from Base.

     object section.



     method-id. "newWithData" 
     linkage section. 
         01 lnkObject      object reference.
         01 lnkName        pic x(80). 

     procedure division using lnkName 
                    returning lnkObject. 

  *----Create a new instance of A using the "new" method from Base
         invoke super "new" returning lnkObject 
  *----Send it an initialize message. 
         invoke lnkObject "initialize" using lnkName
         exit method. 
     end method "newWithData". 
     object.
     object-storage section.    
         01  theName     pic x(80).   

        ...

     method-id. "initialize"

     linkage section. 
        01  lnkName     pic x(80).
     procedure division using lnkName.
  *----Store the initialization parameter in the object's 
  *    instance data
         move lnkName to theName
         exit method.  
     end method "initialize". 

     end object.
     end class "A".
```

but I don't know how to run (both theory and practice). Can any one show me how?
It will be best helping me with another example and explanation.

Comment: in fact I have to learn it as a programming language and then reasoning about its characteristic + paradigm. The project requires me to self-create a big example to represent Cobol paradigm and characteristic. that's why I need to understand how it works

Answer (score 3):

This really doesn't count as an answer to your question. A 
comment added to your original question indicated that your assignment is to 
study and report on the COBOL language and paradigm. If that is your goal, I would
not recommend getting into OO COBOL except as a side-bar issue.

Object oriented extensions to COBOL are, in my opinion, a marketing tool.
OO extensions boil down to window dressing and are not a 
good fit with respect to the origins and traditional strengths of the language.
The nicest thing I can say about OO extensions to COBOL are that they *may* ease some interfacing 
issues encountered when trying to
build Java or other OO based front ends for COBOL transaction processing back ends. And I am not completely convinced of
this either.

COBOL is an excellent language for doing certain tasks in certain environments. See:
[What makes COBOL such a hated language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549399/what-makes-cobol-such-a-hated-language/2554228#2554228)

The COBOL paradigm is that of a third generation imperative language. It is naturally suited
to structured programming where the design emphasis is around "processes" as opposed to "objects".
Take COBOL for what it is, and learn to love it.

Comment: I disagree that OO COBOL is a marketing tool, the use of classes in COBOL programs are important when using .Net or JVM as the target platform.  

Much in the same was as you can CALL C/OS routines, you should also be able to interact with the framework you are executing on via the us of the INVOKE verb.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing like "COBOL paradigm". Don't forget that COBOL is born as a procedural language (with verbose syntax) and therefore "traditional" COBOL followes the paradigm of procedural/structured programming. It's very old but it's still used today, especially in legacy financiary applications. OO COBOL is an extension to this, which means that some additional syntax is added to allow things like object creation, inheritance, etc...By the time it was created, a lot of (better) OO languages were available, so it's largely ignored either in the industry or in the research. However, a few resources are available: this [website](http://home.swbell.net/mck9/cobol/ooc/ooc.html), this [tutorial](http://www.netcobol.com/info/whitepaper/oocoby2k.pdf), I even found a number of books about OO COBOL in [this bibliography](http://theamericanprogrammer.com/books/books.cobol.shtml)..